# Same instances different classes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification

feature 1|feature 2| feature 3|Class   |

---

**1     |    2    |     3    |Class 1 |**

---

1     |    5    |     3    |Class 2 |

---

4     |    9    |     7    |Class 1 |

---

**1     |    2    |     3    |Class 4 |**

---

**1     |    2    |     3    |Class 3 |**

---

2     |    2    |     3    |Class 3 |

---

I have a dataset which is similar to the above. As you can see for the same instance sets, I can have different classes. Which classifier can I apply?

Comment: Which classifier can I apply?? Ha? Try to narrow down your question and show your research thus far.

Comment: As @Aechlys said in his answer, if you have identical rows with different classes, you can turn this problem into a multi-label classification, by grouping the classes based on data.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to predict all classes for a particular datapoint, you are looking for Multi-label classification.

Set of pre-made multi-label classifiers can be found [on this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).